# Can I use credit card images in my payment page

Tags: image, types, payment

Can I use supported credit card images like VISA, MASTER in my payment page? Do I need to seek permission from them? Or it is free to use ? Please suggest..Thanks

Comment: This should get moved to Webmasters, but I will say that use of the logos tends to be granted in the relevant merchant account agreements.  You should read yours (or have your client read theirs) and see what it says about the logos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For VISA:  http://usa.visa.com/about_visa/ask_visa/index.html (my italics):

> **When is the Visa logo available for use?** As a service to authorized Visa card issuers and Visa merchants, Visa makes available electronic artwork of the Visa brand mark and links to Visa proprietary web sites. *Only Visa card issuers and merchants are authorized to use Visa brand marks.* If you are working for a Visa card issuer or Visa merchant, please visit our Marketing Center for Visa logo information and downloads.

For Mastercard: http://www.mastercardbrandcenter.com/us/howtouse/amu_websites.shtml:

This seems less restrictive in that it doesn't specifically *exclude* use for non-merchant uses but I'm pretty certain trademark law would still apply (depending on your jurisdiction of course) and you may get into trouble for misrepresentation.

---

In any case, the best bet in *both* cases is to ask the organisations themselves. If you get permission in writing from the owners of the marks, it's a hard task for them to convince the legal system that you're doing something wrong (unless you use it in a way they *didn't* give you permission for).